# Openpyxl multiple hyperlinks in one cell

Tags: python, hyperlink, openpyxl

How do you put multiple hyperlinks in one cell using openpyxl?

I have tried writing the HYPERLINK function with line breaks like this.

```
links = []
for pdf in pdfs
    links.append('HYPERLINK("file:{0}","{1}")'.format(os.path.abspath(pdf),pdf))
cell.value = '=' + '&CHAR(10)&'.join(links)
```

Although, the linebreaks visually break up the text in the cell, they don't appear to separate the links.  When I hover the mouse over the cell, it is one long string with all links merged.

If I put the links in adjacent columns like this:

```
for col,pdf in enumerate(pdfs):
    cell.offset(0,col).hyperlink = pdf
```

I can open the spreadsheet and manually copy/paste the links into the same cell with each link working.  So I think it should be possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Load the File with _"manually copy/paste the links"_ an inspect how the Links are **separated**. Could be Blank or Comma.

Comment: When openpyxl writes hyperlinks in a cell, only the cell value is displayed in the formula bar.  I can't see the 'HYPERLINK' formula.  I suppose it is hidden.  If I could unhide the formula somehow, inspection may lead to some answers...

Comment: Try simple append twice `links.append(...`.